# Merge con varias tablas en Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo 3 tablas con estas columnas:

analisis_coches_usados:

```
       Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos Comunidad_autonoma  \
0         950      Diésel            2000.0     110.0            Navarra   
1        6200    Gasolina            2017.0      82.0     Islas Canarias   
2       11490    Gasolina            2016.0     130.0             Madrid   
3       28500      Diésel            2017.0     150.0     Islas Baleares   
4        8200      Diésel            2012.0     150.0           Cataluña   
...       ...         ...               ...       ...                ...   
47159   18490    Gasolina            2018.0     140.0          Andalucía   
47160   14500      Diésel            2015.0     150.0          Andalucía   
47161   11000    Gasolina            2019.0      72.0          Andalucía   
47162   47900    Gasolina            2013.0     450.0            Galicia   
47163    2790      Diésel            2006.0      70.0           Cataluña   

                   Marca_y_Modelo Año_Venta Mes_Venta       Año_Comunidad  \
0                     SEAT Toledo      2020        12         2020Navarra   
1                      CITROEN C1      2021        01  2021Islas Canarias   
2                    PEUGEOT 3008      2021        01          2021Madrid   
3      LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport      2021        01  2021Islas Baleares   
4                     HONDA Civic      2020        12        2020Cataluña   
...                           ...       ...       ...                 ...   
47159                 HYUNDAI i30      2020        11       2020Andalucía   
47160              RENAULT Laguna      2021        01       2021Andalucía   
47161                 PEUGEOT 108      2021        01       2021Andalucía   
47162                    AUDI RS4      2021        01         2021Galicia   
47163                  CITROEN C2      2021        01        2021Cataluña
```

salarios1:

```
    Año Periodo Salario_euros_anuales       Comunidad  Unnamed: 3  \
0   2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía         NaN   
1   2021     Año             23.234,63          Aragón         NaN   
2   2021     Año             24.349,02        Asturias         NaN   
3   2021     Año             21.984,88  Islas Baleares         NaN   
4   2021     Año             19.002,85  Islas Canarias         NaN   
..   ...     ...                   ...             ...         ...   
8   2016     Año             21.999,02        La rioja         NaN   
9   2017     Año             22.234,21        La rioja         NaN   
10  2018     Año             22.641,17        La rioja         NaN   
11  2019     Año             22.877,13        La rioja         NaN   
12  2020     Año             23.292,63        La rioja         NaN   

         Año_Comunidad  
0        2021Andalucía  
1           2021Aragón  
2         2021Asturias  
3   2021Islas Baleares  
4   2021Islas Canarias  
..                 ...  
8         2016La rioja  
9         2017La rioja  
10        2018La rioja  
11        2019La rioja  
12        2020La rioja
```

tabla_combustible_comunidades:

```
       Año Mes  Super_95    Diesel Comunidad Año_Comunidad
0     2017  01  1.242500  1.129250   Navarra   2017Navarra
1     2017  02  1.250500  1.129500   Navarra   2017Navarra
2     2017  03  1.229500  1.114750   Navarra   2017Navarra
3     2017  04  1.236667  1.109667   Navarra   2017Navarra
4     2017  05  1.218400  1.090400   Navarra   2017Navarra
...    ...  ..       ...       ...       ...           ...
1185  2022  07  2.041750  2.001000  La Rioja  2022La Rioja
1186  2022  08  1.828600  1.850400  La Rioja  2022La Rioja
1187  2022  09  1.729750  1.879250  La Rioja  2022La Rioja
1188  2022  10  1.733400  1.911600  La Rioja  2022La Rioja
1189  2022  11  1.773667  1.927000  La Rioja  2022La Rioja

[1190 rows x 6 columns]
```

mi intención es que al unirlas se quede así:

```
       Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos Comunidad_autonoma  \
0         950      Diésel            2000.0     110.0            Navarra   
1        6200    Gasolina            2017.0      82.0     Islas Canarias   
2       11490    Gasolina            2016.0     130.0             Madrid   
3       28500      Diésel            2017.0     150.0     Islas Baleares   
4        8200      Diésel            2012.0     150.0           Cataluña   
...       ...         ...               ...       ...                ...   
47159   18490    Gasolina            2018.0     140.0          Andalucía   
47160   14500      Diésel            2015.0     150.0          Andalucía   
47161   11000    Gasolina            2019.0      72.0          Andalucía   
47162   47900    Gasolina            2013.0     450.0            Galicia   
47163    2790      Diésel            2006.0      70.0           Cataluña   

                   Marca_y_Modelo Año_Venta Mes_Venta       Año_Comunidad  \
0                     SEAT Toledo      2020        12         2020Navarra   
1                      CITROEN C1      2021        01  2021Islas Canarias   
2                    PEUGEOT 3008      2021        01          2021Madrid   
3      LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport      2021        01  2021Islas Baleares   
4                     HONDA Civic      2020        12        2020Cataluña   
...                           ...       ...       ...                 ...   
47159                 HYUNDAI i30      2020        11       2020Andalucía   
47160              RENAULT Laguna      2021        01       2021Andalucía   
47161                 PEUGEOT 108      2021        01       2021Andalucía   
47162                    AUDI RS4      2021        01         2021Galicia   
47163                  CITROEN C2      2021        01        2021Cataluña   

      Año_x Periodo Salario_euros_anuales     Comunidad_x  Unnamed: 3 Año_y  \
0      2020     Año             27.995,96         Navarra         NaN  2020   
1      2021     Año             19.002,85  Islas Canarias         NaN  2021   
2      2021     Año             29.333,42          Madrid         NaN  2021   
3      2021     Año             21.984,88  Islas Baleares         NaN  2021   
4      2020     Año             27.100,11        Cataluña         NaN  2020   
...     ...     ...                   ...             ...         ...   ...   
47159  2020     Año             22.323,85       Andalucía         NaN  2020   
47160  2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía         NaN  2021   
47161  2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía         NaN  2021   
47162  2021     Año             21.856,41         Galicia         NaN  2021   
47163  2021     Año             25.991,81        Cataluña         NaN  2021   

      Mes  Super_95    Diesel     Comunidad_y  
0      12    1.1770  1.058667         Navarra  
1      01    1.2080  1.092000  Islas Canarias  
2      01    1.2080  1.092000          Madrid  
3      01    1.2080  1.092000  Islas Baleares  
4      12    1.1770  1.058667        Cataluña  
...    ..       ...       ...             ...  
47159  11    1.1528  1.026400       Andalucía  
47160  01    1.2080  1.092000       Andalucía  
47161  01    1.2080  1.092000       Andalucía  
47162  01    1.2080  1.092000         Galicia  
47163  01    1.2080  1.092000        Cataluña
```

Este es el resultado que me da.. el problema es que deja muchisimos nulos o se me multiplican los valores, este es mi código:

```
analisis2= pd.merge(coches_usados, salarios1,  how='left',
                     left_on=['Año_Comunidad'], right_on = ['Año_Comunidad'])


analisis_coches_usados= pd.merge(analisis2, tabla_combustible_comunidades,  how='left',
                   left_on=['Año_Comunidad','Mes_Venta'], right_on = ['Año_Comunidad','Mes'])
```

he probado así de varías maneras, nunca me da error, pero o se me multiplican los valores y me da una tabla de 500.00 o muchas filas null ¿Qué puedo hacer para resolverlo?

He estado investigando y todos los valores están igual escritos y son del mismo tipo,támpoco hay valores null en las 3 tablas que quiero unir ¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

El valor común en todas las tablas es :Año_Comunidad

añado otra muestra de mis tablas:

tabla coches

```
      Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos    Comunidad_autonoma  \
7959     7999    Gasolina            2012.0     125.0              Cataluña   
5573     8900      Diésel            2009.0     175.0              Cataluña   
10760   15500      Diésel            2020.0      90.0              Cataluña   
17621   42199      Diésel            2015.0     272.0             Andalucía   
49985     500    Gasolina            2002.0      81.0            País Vasco   
16375   12000      Diésel            2004.0     125.0             Andalucía   
45558   22000    Gasolina            2019.0     177.0              Cataluña   
36931    1990      Diésel            2004.0     120.0             Cantabria   
43787    3000      Diésel            2001.0      90.0               Galicia   
46818    5500      Diésel            2002.0     180.0                Murcia   
32925    4100      Diésel            2008.0      90.0           Extremadura   
39104   19300     Híbrido            2020.0     122.0                Madrid   
18788    5500      Diésel            2011.0     120.0             Andalucía   
8075     3700      Diésel            2006.0     112.0  Comunidad Valenciana   
42293    7000    Gasolina            2004.0     192.0              Cataluña   
33736    9900      Diésel            2014.0     115.0               Galicia   
20087   11250      Diésel            2016.0     115.0                Madrid   
38381   23999      Diésel            2020.0     120.0                Murcia   
31231   51900    Gasolina            2020.0     224.0       Castilla y León   
28020   14000    Gasolina            2008.0     125.0                Madrid   

                  Marca_y_Modelo Año_Venta Mes_Venta             Año_Comunidad  
7959                  FORD Focus      2021        01              2021Cataluña  
5573                  VOLVO XC60      2020        11              2020Cataluña  
10760               RENAULT Clio      2020        12              2020Cataluña  
17621                    AUDI Q7      2021        01             2021Andalucía  
49985             HYUNDAI Accent      2020        12            2020País Vasco  
16375             SANTANA Anibal      2020        12             2020Andalucía  
45558             HYUNDAI TUCSON      2020        10              2020Cataluña  
36931               MAZDA Mazda6      2020        11             2020Cantabria  
43787      VOLKSWAGEN New Beetle      2020        11               2020Galicia  
46818          VOLKSWAGEN Amarok      2020        12                2020Murcia  
32925            VOLKSWAGEN Golf      2020        12           2020Extremadura  
39104             TOYOTA Corolla      2021        01                2021Madrid  
18788   CITROEN Grand C4 Picasso      2021        01             2021Andalucía  
8075              HYUNDAI Trajet      2020        11  2020Comunidad Valenciana  
42293                BMW Serie 3      2020        11              2020Cataluña  
33736    VOLVO V40 Cross Country      2021        01               2021Galicia  
20087  VOLKSWAGEN Golf Sportsvan      2021        01                2021Madrid  
38381                 FORD Focus      2021        01                2021Murcia  
31231          MERCEDES-BENZ GLB      2020        12       2020Castilla y León  
28020                 FORD Focus      2020        11                2020Madrid
```

tabla combustible:

```
       Año Mes  Super_95    Diesel             Comunidad  \
526   2020  01  1.321750  1.246000             Cantabria   
816   2020  12  1.177000  1.058667  Comunidad Valenciana   
474   2021  08  1.416600  1.265000        Islas Canarias   
261   2021  05  1.345800  1.203800             Andalucía   
391   2020  06  1.098500  1.005000        Islas Baleares   
404   2021  08  1.416600  1.265000        Islas Baleares   
739   2020  04  1.106667  1.020000              Cataluña   
886   2020  12  1.177000  1.058667               Galicia   
325   2020  11  1.152800  1.026400              Asturias   
673   2020  09  1.162333  1.034667       Castilla y León   
390   2020  05  1.078750  0.986250        Islas Baleares   
878   2020  03  1.224800  1.126200               Galicia   
1169  2021  03  1.305200  1.177600              La Rioja   
122   2021  06  1.370750  1.234500           Extremadura   
1028  2021  02  1.246250  1.128000                Murcia   
1027  2021  01  1.208000  1.092000                Murcia   
1173  2021  07  1.402250  1.262250              La Rioja   
895   2021  09  1.431000  1.277000               Galicia   
1103  2021  07  1.402250  1.262250            País Vasco   
457   2020  02  1.301000  1.207250        Islas Canarias   
877   2020  02  1.301000  1.207250               Galicia   
1031  2021  05  1.345800  1.203800                Murcia   
1097  2021  01  1.208000  1.092000            País Vasco   
52    2021  06  1.370750  1.234500               Navarra   
322   2020  08  1.161500  1.060500              Asturias   

                 Año_Comunidad  
526              2020Cantabria  
816   2020Comunidad Valenciana  
474         2021Islas Canarias  
261              2021Andalucía  
391         2020Islas Baleares  
404         2021Islas Baleares  
739               2020Cataluña  
886                2020Galicia  
325               2020Asturias  
673        2020Castilla y León  
390         2020Islas Baleares  
878                2020Galicia  
1169              2021La Rioja  
122            2021Extremadura  
1028                2021Murcia  
1027                2021Murcia  
1173              2021La Rioja  
895                2021Galicia  
1103            2021País Vasco  
457         2020Islas Canarias  
877                2020Galicia  
1031                2021Murcia  
1097            2021País Vasco  
52                 2021Navarra  
322               2020Asturias
```

y tabla salarios:

```
Año Periodo Salario_euros_anuales             Comunidad  Unnamed: 3  \
12  2020     Año             22.834,66               Galicia         NaN   
5   2021     Año             22.299,82             Cantabria         NaN   
12  2020     Año             22.856,70  Comunidad Valenciana         NaN   
12  2020     Año             22.323,85             Andalucía         NaN   
12  2020     Año             27.995,96               Navarra         NaN   
12  2020     Año             30.224,16            País Vasco         NaN   
9   2021     Año             21.751,09  Comunidad Valenciana         NaN   
7   2021     Año             21.968,28       Castilla y León         NaN   
14  2021     Año             26.016,27               Navarra         NaN   
0   2021     Año             21.218,95             Andalucía         NaN   
12  2020     Año             22.948,76       Castilla y León         NaN   
2   2021     Año             24.349,02              Asturias         NaN   
12  2020     Año             27.100,11              Cataluña         NaN   
10  2021     Año             19.435,81           Extremadura         NaN   
12  2020     Año             22.575,01    Castilla la Mancha         NaN   
13  2021     Año             21.780,62                Murcia         NaN   
12  2020     Año             23.495,12             Cantabria         NaN   
12  2021     Año             29.333,42                Madrid         NaN   
3   2021     Año             21.984,88        Islas Baleares         NaN   
6   2021     Año             21.412,67    Castilla la Mancha         NaN   

               Año_Comunidad  
12               2020Galicia  
5              2021Cantabria  
12  2020Comunidad Valenciana  
12             2020Andalucía  
12               2020Navarra  
12            2020País Vasco  
9   2021Comunidad Valenciana  
7        2021Castilla y León  
14               2021Navarra  
0              2021Andalucía  
12       2020Castilla y León  
2               2021Asturias  
12              2020Cataluña  
10           2021Extremadura  
12    2020Castilla la Mancha  
13                2021Murcia  
12             2020Cantabria  
12                2021Madrid  
3         2021Islas Baleares
```

edición nueva, si tengo esos valores:

```
combus31=tabla_combustible_comunidades.loc[(tabla_combustible_comunidades['Año_Comunidad']=='2021Cataluña')]
    Año Mes  Super_95    Diesel Comunidad Año_Comunidad
747  2021  01  1.208000  1.092000  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
748  2021  02  1.246250  1.128000  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
749  2021  03  1.305200  1.177600  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
750  2021  04  1.320333  1.180667  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
etc

salarios31=salarios1.loc[(salarios1['Año_Comunidad']=='2020Murcia')|(salarios1['Año_Comunidad']=='2020Extremadura')]

     Año Mes  Super_95    Diesel Comunidad Año_Comunidad
747  2021  01  1.208000  1.092000  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
748  2021  02  1.246250  1.128000  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
749  2021  03  1.305200  1.177600  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
750  2021  04  1.320333  1.180667  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
751  2021  05  1.345800  1.203800  Cataluña  2021Cataluña
```

Comment: puede parecer una pequeña chapucilla pero prueba quitar los títulos de todas las tablas y luego de ahí crea un nuevo dataframe con los datos y poniéndole los títulos

Comment: Buenos días juank, también quito el titulo de la columna común?

Comment: sabia pregunta, las tablas tienen el mismo número de columnas?

Comment: no, cada tabla es de su padre y de su madre...

Comment: @Anita, estoy intentando replicar tu código pero no es posible porque el primer merge que haces va sobre la columna "Año_Comunidad", pero la tabla `salarios1` no tiene esa columna

Comment: @abulafia ya está modificado.. lo copie mal en el foro muchas gracias por avisar

Comment: @juank he probado a borrar los nombres de las columnas menos  Año_Comunidad, con este codigo:analisis2= pd.merge(coches_usados2, salarios2,  how='left',
                     left_on=['Año_Comunidad'], right_on = ['Año_Comunidad'])


analisis_coches_usados2= pd.merge(analisis2, tabla_combustible_comunidades,  how='left',
                   left_on=['Año_Comunidad'], right_on = ['Año_Comunidad']). al final sigue el mismo error , la tabla pasa a a tener 541053 filas :(

Comment: aunque en los datos que no casen, y salgan como "None" puedes sacar y poner la media de ella y sustituir el valor "None" por la media de esos valores

Comment: @juank necesito los originales, es para un trabajo final y me lo van a mirar con lupa, no entiendo porque no va

Answer (score 1):

**Nota**. Quizás esto debería ser un comentario, pues no es propiamente una respuesta (de momento), pero es demasiado extenso para caber en un comentario. Cuando tenga más información podré editarla y convertirla en una respuesta definitiva.

Yo creo que los `merge` que estás haciendo son correctos, pero es difícil verificarlo sin tener tus datos. Los dataframes que proporcionas de ejemplo son solo fragmentos y no la información completa y tratando de utilizar esos datos para replicar tu ejemplo sí que me salen montones de `NaN`, pero es normal ya que no hay datos para "casar".

Por ejemplo en tu tabla de precios de combustibles los datos visibles corresponden a los años 2017 y 2022, pero ninguno de esos años son los que se ven en la tabla de coches usados, que usa los años 2020 y 2021. Por tanto, al no haber datos de precios de combustible para los años 2020 y 2021 salen todo NaN en las columnas correspondientes a esos precios tras el merge.

Voy a proporcionar aqui otros datos de ejemplo basados en los tuyos pero retocados para que todo case. Para que mi ejemplo sea replicable, proporciono los datos como texto en cadenas y los leo con `pd.read_table()`.

```
data1 = """
Precio   Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo    Caballos   Comunidad_autonoma               Marca_y_Modelo   Año_Venta   Mes_Venta         Año_Comunidad 
   950        Diésel            2000.0       110.0              Navarra                  SEAT Toledo        2020          01           2020Navarra 
  6200      Gasolina            2017.0        82.0       Islas Canarias                   CITROEN C1        2021          01    2021Islas Canarias 
 11490      Gasolina            2016.0       130.0               Madrid                 PEUGEOT 3008        2021          01            2021Madrid 
 28500        Diésel            2017.0       150.0       Islas Baleares   LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport        2021          01    2021Islas Baleares 
  8200        Diésel            2012.0       150.0             Cataluña                  HONDA Civic        2020          12          2020Cataluña 
 18490      Gasolina            2018.0       140.0            Andalucía                  HYUNDAI i30        2020          11         2020Andalucía 
 14500        Diésel            2015.0       150.0            Andalucía               RENAULT Laguna        2021          01         2021Andalucía 
 11000      Gasolina            2019.0        72.0            Andalucía                  PEUGEOT 108        2021          01         2021Andalucía 
 47900      Gasolina            2013.0       450.0              Galicia                     AUDI RS4        2021          01           2021Galicia 
  2790        Diésel            2006.0        70.0             Cataluña                   CITROEN C2        2021          01          2021Cataluña
"""
data2 = """
 Año   Periodo   Salario_euros_anuales        Comunidad         Año_Comunidad
2020       Año               27.995,96          Navarra           2020Navarra
2021       Año               19.002,85   Islas Canarias    2021Islas Canarias
2021       Año               29.333,42           Madrid            2021Madrid
2021       Año               21.984,88   Islas Baleares    2021Islas Baleares
2020       Año               27.100,11         Cataluña          2020Cataluña
2020       Año               22.323,85        Andalucía         2020Andalucía
2021       Año               21.218,95        Andalucía         2021Andalucía
2021       Año               21.218,95        Andalucía         2021Andalucía
2021       Año               21.856,41          Galicia           2021Galicia
2021       Año               25.991,81         Cataluña          2021Cataluña
"""
data3 = """
 Año   Mes   Super_95     Diesel       Comunidad       Año_Comunidad
2020    01   1.242500   1.129250         Navarra         2020Navarra
2020    02   1.250500   1.129500         Navarra         2020Navarra
2020    03   1.229500   1.114750         Navarra         2020Navarra
2020    11   1.236667   1.109667       Andalucía       2020Andalucía
2020    12   1.218400   1.090400        Cataluña        2020Cataluña
2021    01   2.041750   2.001000          Madrid          2021Madrid
2021    01   1.828600   1.850400       Andalucía       2021Andalucía
2021    01   1.729750   1.879250         Galicia         2021Galicia
2021    01   1.733400   1.911600  Islas Baleares  2021Islas Baleares
2021    01   1.773667   1.927000        Cataluña        2021Cataluña
"""
```

Observa que he usado para `data1` los datos de ejemplo sobre coches usados de tu pregunta. Para `data2` he usado los datos que habías proporcionado inicialmente, antes de que editaras la pregunta, pues correspondían a las mismas fechas que las que hay en `data1` (pero he añadido la columna "Año_Comunidad" que faltaba). Y para `data3` me he basado en la tercera tabla que proporcionas, pero cambiando años y comunidades para que casen con los usados en tabla1 y tabla2.

Leo estas tablas así:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

coches_usados = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data1), sep="\s\s+")
salarios1 = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data2), sep="\s\s+")
tabla_combustible_comunidades = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data3), sep="\s\s+")
```

y ejecuto tus merge:

```
analisis2= pd.merge(coches_usados, salarios1,  how='left',
                     left_on=['Año_Comunidad'], right_on = ['Año_Comunidad'])

analisis_coches_usados= pd.merge(analisis2, tabla_combustible_comunidades,  how='left',
                   left_on=['Año_Comunidad','Mes_Venta'], right_on = ['Año_Comunidad','Mes'])
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

```
    Precio Combustible  Año_del_vehiculo  Caballos Comunidad_autonoma  \
0      950      Diésel            2000.0     110.0            Navarra   
1     6200    Gasolina            2017.0      82.0     Islas Canarias   
2    11490    Gasolina            2016.0     130.0             Madrid   
3    28500      Diésel            2017.0     150.0     Islas Baleares   
4     8200      Diésel            2012.0     150.0           Cataluña   
5    18490    Gasolina            2018.0     140.0          Andalucía   
6    14500      Diésel            2015.0     150.0          Andalucía   
7    14500      Diésel            2015.0     150.0          Andalucía   
8    11000    Gasolina            2019.0      72.0          Andalucía   
9    11000    Gasolina            2019.0      72.0          Andalucía   
10   47900    Gasolina            2013.0     450.0            Galicia   
11    2790      Diésel            2006.0      70.0           Cataluña   

                Marca_y_Modelo  Año_Venta  Mes_Venta       Año_Comunidad  \
0                  SEAT Toledo       2020          1         2020Navarra   
1                   CITROEN C1       2021          1  2021Islas Canarias   
2                 PEUGEOT 3008       2021          1          2021Madrid   
3   LAND-ROVER Discovery Sport       2021          1  2021Islas Baleares   
4                  HONDA Civic       2020         12        2020Cataluña   
5                  HYUNDAI i30       2020         11       2020Andalucía   
6               RENAULT Laguna       2021          1       2021Andalucía   
7               RENAULT Laguna       2021          1       2021Andalucía   
8                  PEUGEOT 108       2021          1       2021Andalucía   
9                  PEUGEOT 108       2021          1       2021Andalucía   
10                    AUDI RS4       2021          1         2021Galicia   
11                  CITROEN C2       2021          1        2021Cataluña   

    Año_x Periodo Salario_euros_anuales     Comunidad_x   Año_y   Mes  \
0    2020     Año             27.995,96         Navarra  2020.0   1.0   
1    2021     Año             19.002,85  Islas Canarias     NaN   NaN   
2    2021     Año             29.333,42          Madrid  2021.0   1.0   
3    2021     Año             21.984,88  Islas Baleares  2021.0   1.0   
4    2020     Año             27.100,11        Cataluña  2020.0  12.0   
5    2020     Año             22.323,85       Andalucía  2020.0  11.0   
6    2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía  2021.0   1.0   
7    2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía  2021.0   1.0   
8    2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía  2021.0   1.0   
9    2021     Año             21.218,95       Andalucía  2021.0   1.0   
10   2021     Año             21.856,41         Galicia  2021.0   1.0   
11   2021     Año             25.991,81        Cataluña  2021.0   1.0   

    Super_95    Diesel     Comunidad_y  
0   1.242500  1.129250         Navarra  
1        NaN       NaN             NaN  
2   2.041750  2.001000          Madrid  
3   1.733400  1.911600  Islas Baleares  
4   1.218400  1.090400        Cataluña  
5   1.236667  1.109667       Andalucía  
6   1.828600  1.850400       Andalucía  
7   1.828600  1.850400       Andalucía  
8   1.828600  1.850400       Andalucía  
9   1.828600  1.850400       Andalucía  
10  1.729750  1.879250         Galicia  
11  1.773667  1.927000        Cataluña
```

Donde puedes ver cómo aparecen correctamente rellenadas todas las columnas. Se observan unos NaN (que he dejado a propósito) en la fila 1. Ello se debe a que no hay en la tabla 3 datos de precio de combustible para las Islas Canarias para el año 2021, mes 01.

**Observa otro detalle**. El resultado tiene más filas que los dataframes de entrada. La entrada tenía 10 filas, la salida tiene 12. Mirando con detalle vemos que hay filas "repetidas" correspondientes a los coches "RENAULT Laguna" y "PEUGEOT 108". Esto se debe a que la tabla de salarios tiene dos entradas (¿repetidas?) para Andalucia2021, que es la comunidad y año de venta de esos dos vehículos. Así que las dos entradas repetidas de la tabla de salarios causa que se repitan todas las filas de la tabla de vehículos usados en las que se haya vendido un coche en ese año y en esa comunidad.

Si tus tablas reales contienen más entradas repetidas de este tipo eso podría causar que la tabla con el merge final aumente desmesuradamente. Y los NaN se deberían a que no hay datos de precios de combustible para esos meses y comunidades.

¿Podrías suministrar de ejemplo otros datos que muestren el problema que tienes?

### Actualización

He replicado el experimento con los datos nuevos aportados en la pregunta. La tabla resultante efectivamente presenta muchos NaN, pero todos son perfectamente explicables por la ausencia de datos con los que correlacionar.

Por ejemplo, adjunto una imagen de la tabla resultante del merge (usando los datos nuevos de la pregunta), para comentar algunas cosas:

[image: Tabla resultado]

Vemos algunos `NaN` en la zona 1. Esos son resultado del primer merge, debido a que la primera tabla tiene filas referidas a `2020Murcia` y `2020Extremadura`, pero la segunda tabla (salarios) no tiene datos para ese Año_Comunidad.

Luego vemos montones y montones de NaN en la zona 2. Esos indican que no hay datos de precios de combustibles para el año, mes y comunidad en cuestión. En efecto, fíjate por ejemplo en la fila 0. Corresponde a una venta para el mes 1 en 2021Cataluña, pero si buscas en la tabla de combustibles ves que no hay entrada para `2021Cataluña`, mes 1. Y así con todas las demás.

Hay una excepción en la zona 3. Eso corresponde a una venta en el mes 1 en 2021Murcia, y para ese mes, año y comunidad sí que tenemos precio de combustible en la tabla `tabla_combustible_comunidades` y por eso en esa fila no hay NaN, sino los datos de ese precio.

En definitiva, los NaN que aparecen se deben a datos ausentes y no es un error del merge. Si tu merge no te da lo que esperas es que probablemente las tablas de entrada no tienen los datos apropiados y necesitan ser generadas/procesadas mejor.

Comment: si, voy a ello..

Comment: un caso sumamente complejo, por el tema datos que se manejan, quizá habría que buscar más coincidencias con los datos y probar a usar **concat** en caso de que sea una nueva colmna

Comment: aqui van parte de mis tablas mejoradas, edito la pregunta

Comment: @juank como se haría eso que dices?

Comment: @juank  he actualizado con tu respuesta

Comment: @Anitta Te refieres a mi respuesta? No soy juank. De cualquier forma yo quería decir que esos datos no están en el extracto de los dataframes que aparecen en tu pregunta, y por eso (porque yo me he basado en esos extractos para hacer pruebas) me salen esos NaN en los resultados. Si tú sí tienes esos datos, no deberían salirte esos NaN. Si te salen otros corresponderán igualmente a datos que no tienes